# Trouble implementing code example using PInvoke Declarations

Tags: c#, tooltip, pinvoke, tray

I am referencing the following thread here for my question:

[Get ToolTip Text from Icon in System Tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366505/get-tooltip-text-from-icon-in-system-tray)

I basically want to do the same thing as the OP, but unlike some other users who responded to this thread, I am having trouble getting the code to work after adding in the missing PInvoke declarations that were not explicitly defined in the code samples. I assembled a class file that attempts to put everything together and I referenced the declarations from PInvoke.net (i'm not sure if this is what user michalczerwinski did or if he was using some sort of PInvoke library). here's what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Example
{

    public static class TrayTooltip
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
        {
            All = 0x001F0FFF,
            Terminate = 0x00000001,
            CreateThread = 0x00000002,
            VirtualMemoryOperation = 0x00000008,
            VirtualMemoryRead = 0x00000010,
            VirtualMemoryWrite = 0x00000020,
            DuplicateHandle = 0x00000040,
            CreateProcess = 0x000000080,
            SetQuota = 0x00000100,
            SetInformation = 0x00000200,
            QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
            QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000,
            Synchronize = 0x00100000
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum AllocationType
        {
            Commit = 0x1000,
            Reserve = 0x2000,
            Decommit = 0x4000,
            Release = 0x8000,
            Reset = 0x80000,
            Physical = 0x400000,
            TopDown = 0x100000,
            WriteWatch = 0x200000,
            LargePages = 0x20000000
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum MemoryProtection
        {
            Execute = 0x10,
            ExecuteRead = 0x20,
            ExecuteReadWrite = 0x40,
            ExecuteWriteCopy = 0x80,
            NoAccess = 0x01,
            ReadOnly = 0x02,
            ReadWrite = 0x04,
            WriteCopy = 0x08,
            GuardModifierflag = 0x100,
            NoCacheModifierflag = 0x200,
            WriteCombineModifierflag = 0x400
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum TB
        {
            WM_USER = 0x0400,
            GETBUTTON = (WM_USER + 23),
            GETBUTTONTEXTW = (WM_USER + 75),
            BUTTONCOUNT = (WM_USER + 24)
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct TBBUTTON
        {
            public int cbSize;
            public int dwMask;
            public int idCommand;
            public int iImage;
            public byte fsState;
            public byte fsStyle;
            public short cx;
            public IntPtr lParam;
            public IntPtr pszText;
            public int cchText;
        }

        public static class User32
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

            // When you don't want the ProcessId, use this overload and pass IntPtr.Zero for the second parameter
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, ref IntPtr lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        }

        public static class Kernel32
        {
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags processAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int processId);
            public static IntPtr OpenProcess(Process proc, ProcessAccessFlags flags)
            {
                return OpenProcess(flags, false, proc.Id);
            }

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, AllocationType flAllocationType, MemoryProtection flProtect);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] object lpBuffer, int dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
            public static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, int dwSize, AllocationType dwFreeType);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
            public static unsafe extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, byte* pAddress, int size, AllocationType freeType);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
            [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hWndParent, IntPtr hWndChildAfter, string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        static IntPtr GetSystemTrayHandle()
        {
            IntPtr hWndTray = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);
            if (hWndTray != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                hWndTray = FindWindowEx(hWndTray, IntPtr.Zero, "TrayNotifyWnd", null);
                if (hWndTray != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    hWndTray = FindWindowEx(hWndTray, IntPtr.Zero, "SysPager", null);
                    if (hWndTray != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        hWndTray = FindWindowEx(hWndTray, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", null);
                        return hWndTray;
                    }
                }
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        private static unsafe bool GetTBButton(IntPtr hToolbar, int i, ref TBBUTTON tbButton, ref string text, ref IntPtr ipWindowHandle)
        {
            // One page
            const int BUFFER_SIZE = 0x1000;

            byte[] localBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

            UInt32 processId = 0;
            UInt32 threadId = User32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hToolbar, out processId);

            IntPtr hProcess = Kernel32.OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, (int)processId);
            if (hProcess == IntPtr.Zero) { Debug.Assert(false); return false; }

            IntPtr ipRemoteBuffer = Kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)BUFFER_SIZE, AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);

            if (ipRemoteBuffer == IntPtr.Zero) { Debug.Assert(false); return false; }

            // TBButton
            fixed (TBBUTTON* pTBButton = &tbButton)
            {
                IntPtr ipTBButton = new IntPtr(pTBButton);

                int b = (int)User32.SendMessage(hToolbar, (int)TB.GETBUTTON, i, ref ipRemoteBuffer);
                if (b == 0)
                {
                    Debug.Assert(false);
                    return false;
                }

                // this is fixed
                Int32 dwBytesRead = 0;
                IntPtr ipBytesRead = new IntPtr(&dwBytesRead);

                bool b2 = Kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, ipRemoteBuffer, ipTBButton, sizeof(TBBUTTON), out ipBytesRead);

                if (!b2)
                {
                    Debug.Assert(false);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // button text
            fixed (byte* pLocalBuffer = localBuffer)
            {
                IntPtr ipLocalBuffer = new IntPtr(pLocalBuffer);

                int chars = (int)User32.SendMessage(hToolbar, (int)TB.GETBUTTONTEXTW, tbButton.idCommand, ipRemoteBuffer);
                if (chars == -1) { Debug.Assert(false); return false; }

                // this is fixed
                Int32 dwBytesRead = 0;
                IntPtr ipBytesRead = new IntPtr(&dwBytesRead);

                bool b4 = Kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(
                    hProcess,
                    ipRemoteBuffer,
                    ipLocalBuffer,
                    BUFFER_SIZE,
                    out ipBytesRead);

                if (!b4) { Debug.Assert(false); return false; }

                text = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ipLocalBuffer, chars);

                if (text == " ") text = String.Empty;
            }

            Kernel32.VirtualFreeEx(
                hProcess,
                ipRemoteBuffer,
                0,
                AllocationType.Release);

            Kernel32.CloseHandle(hProcess);

            return true;
        }

        public static void ScanToolbarButtons()
        {
            IntPtr _ToolbarWindowHandle = GetSystemTrayHandle();
            UInt32 count = (UInt32)User32.SendMessage(_ToolbarWindowHandle.ToInt32(), (uint)TB.BUTTONCOUNT, 0, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                TBBUTTON tbButton = new TBBUTTON();
                string text = String.Empty;
                IntPtr ipWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

                bool b = GetTBButton(_ToolbarWindowHandle, i, ref tbButton, ref text, ref ipWindowHandle);

                Debug.Print(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles ok, but when I try to execute the ScanToolbarButtons() function, it crashes my windows explorer when it gets to this line here in the GetTBButton function:

```
int b = (int)User32.SendMessage(hToolbar, (int)TB.GETBUTTON, i, ref ipRemoteBuffer);
```

I'm no expert on Windows API programming and have no idea what is causing this. Could someone take a look and let me know what you think?

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: What version of windows are you trying to run this on?

Comment: Would be a lot easier to do this in C++ in Mixed mode CLR, you can build that as a .Net DLL and thunk into it and then call it like a managed assembly in c#.  There's tons of documents on C++ for doing this, and the Windows Api headers are all already in C++.  Additionally you wouldn't have to compile  your app with unsafe code enabled.

I actually do almost all my interop this way, as it's much easier to thunk into managed C++ in C++ exposing stuff as regular .net code, without littering my .net code with tons of interop.

Comment: @vasily.sib, No there were no exceptions thrown in my code. The program continued on as normal, but Explorer just crashed.

Comment: @Ryan Mann, the computer I'm testing on is running Windows 7 Pro SP3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are issues with the original code, so here is a version that should work better. Note it must run in the same bitness (32-bit vs 64-bit) as the operating system (explorer) to work, otherwise, it won't read anything. Also, it does not need to be compiled as `unsafe`.

```
public static void ScanToolbarButtons()
{
    var handle = GetSystemTrayHandle();
    if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        return;

    var count = SendMessage(handle, TB_BUTTONCOUNT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero).ToInt32();
    if (count == 0)
        return;

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out var pid);
    var hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pid);
    if (hProcess == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

    var size = (IntPtr)Marshal.SizeOf<TBBUTTONINFOW>();
    var buffer = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (buffer == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var btn = new TBBUTTONINFOW();
        btn.cbSize = size.ToInt32();
        btn.dwMask = TBIF_BYINDEX | TBIF_COMMAND;
        if (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, buffer, ref btn, size, out var written))
        {
            // we want the identifier
            var res = SendMessage(handle, TB_GETBUTTONINFOW, (IntPtr)i, buffer);
            if (res.ToInt32() >= 0)
            {
                if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, buffer, ref btn, size, out var read))
                {
                    // now get display text using the identifier
                    // first pass we ask for size
                    var textSize = SendMessage(handle, TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW, (IntPtr)btn.idCommand, IntPtr.Zero);
                    if (textSize.ToInt32() != -1)
                    {
                        // we need to allocate for the terminating zero and unicode
                        var utextSize = (IntPtr)((1 + textSize.ToInt32()) * 2);
                        var textBuffer = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, utextSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
                        if (textBuffer != IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            res = SendMessage(handle, TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW, (IntPtr)btn.idCommand, textBuffer);
                            if (res == textSize)
                            {
                                var localBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(utextSize.ToInt32());
                                if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, textBuffer, localBuffer, utextSize, out read))
                                {
                                    var text = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(localBuffer);
                                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                                }
                                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(localBuffer);
                            }
                            VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, textBuffer, IntPtr.Zero, MEM_RELEASE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, buffer, IntPtr.Zero, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}

private static IntPtr GetSystemTrayHandle()
{
    var hwnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell_TrayWnd", null);
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "TrayNotifyWnd", null);
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "SysPager", null);
    return FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", null);
}

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, ref TBBUTTONINFOW lpBuffer, IntPtr nSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, ref TBBUTTONINFOW lpBuffer, IntPtr nSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, IntPtr lpBuffer, IntPtr nSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, int flAllocationType, int flProtect);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, int dwFreeType);

[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hWndParent, IntPtr hWndChildAfter, string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

private const int TBIF_BYINDEX = unchecked((int)0x80000000); // this specifies that the wparam in Get/SetButtonInfo is an index, not id
private const int TBIF_COMMAND = 0x20;
private const int MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000;
private const int MEM_RELEASE = 0x8000;
private const int PAGE_READWRITE = 0x4;
private const int TB_GETBUTTONINFOW = 1087;
private const int TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW = 1099;
private const int TB_BUTTONCOUNT = 1048;

private static bool IsWindowsVistaOrAbove() => Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6;
private static int PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS => IsWindowsVistaOrAbove() ? 0x001FFFFF : 0x001F0FFF;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct TBBUTTONINFOW
{
    public int cbSize;
    public int dwMask;
    public int idCommand;
    public int iImage;
    public byte fsState;
    public byte fsStyle;
    public short cx;
    public IntPtr lParam;
    public IntPtr pszText;
    public int cchText;
}
```

Comment: When I tried to compile this code snippet, it gave me an error on the line with `GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out var pid);` having an issue not recognizing the second parameter. I then declared pid as an int above this lie and then just removed the var term to make it happy. There were a couple of other spots where it threw the same error for input parameters so I replaced them in a similar manner with their appropriate datatypes.

Comment: Now the code runs, but breaks out of the loop at this line, `var res = SendMessage(handle, TB_GETBUTTONINFOW, (IntPtr)i, buffer);` getting a return value of -1 for res. On my test computer (running Windows 7 SP3), I have four icons in my tray, which the program is correctly recognizing (Dropbox, Battery/Plugged in icon, WiFi icon, and Speaker. I'm not sure what the error is or why it would not be able to get the identifier. Any Ideas? There is a non-zero value inside the handle variable that is being passed in.

Comment: If your Windows is 64-bit you must compile your .NET program as 64-bit. The var error is because you have an old C# compiler.

Comment: Brilliant! After changing the setting to compile for 64-bit, it's working beautifully! Thank you all for your help!!!

Comment: Does anybody know how to extend the method `ScanToolbarButtons()` from @SimonMourier in such a way, it prints out the process id of the given tray icon?

Comment: @SUSiS - you should ask another question